# jupyter notebook not working Mac despite being installed

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I have jupyter notebook installed but when I try and open it I get this error. Any idea why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
```

Comment: its ```jupyter notebook``` not ```jupyter-notebook```. just remove the dash sign and add a space in that place

Comment: Encountered the same issue...

Comment: If you run `jupyter --version`, does jupyter-notebook show up as installed?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to switch to python3.

I would advise to check if python3 is installed by running
`python3 --version`

If it is installed, `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and `pip3 install jupyter` should solve your problem, as jupyter should use python 3 in its kernel after that.

If python3 is not installed, I would suggest installing it, after which repeat the step above.

Answer (score 2):

not above!
1-run
<< brew cask install anaconda >>
on terminal

after that anaconda was successfully install...

2- run
<< export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" >>
on terminal

3- run
<< source ~/.zshrc >>
on terminal and close then open terminal again

4- now run
<< jupyter notebook >>
on terminal

now notebook will show on this path:
http://localhost:8888/tree

That's all

Comment: This helped me get the right path in my Quick Action to convert these annoying notebooks to py files